# Static functions swift

Tags: swift

IsOk function has access to that static variables MinAge and MaxAge , i want to ask deos the function IsOk can access to the normal variable Avg ?

```
struct Person {

static var MinAge=0 , MaxAge=120
var Avg: Int = 0

static func IsOk(num:Int) -> Bool {

   return num=>MinAge && num<=MaxAge

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Nope, static cannot access instance variables. For obvious reasons.

Answer (score 3):

**NO**

`static` function cannot access `instance` variable. Think this way: You can call `static func` without instantiating the class object, so how will the `instance variable` be available?